# OpenCV imshow window rendering off screen; how do I move an imshow window?

Tags: python, opencv

I've a function that grabs a screenshot of a named application window and displays it with `cv.imshow`

However the window is rendering off screen.

```
import cv2 as cv

def videoLoop():
    window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('App')[0]
    haystack_img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(750, 30, 1150, 78))
    haystack_img_np = np.array(haystack_img)
    haystack = cv.cvtColor(haystack_img_np, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    test = cv.imshow("Ship Detection", haystack)
    cv.moveWindow(test, 1000,800)
    cv.waitKey(1)
```

I've tried using `cv.moveWindow` but I'm getting a `NULL` error.

```
Failed capture: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp:1515: error: (-27:Null pointer) NULL window: '' in function 'cvMoveWindow'
```

I can also spawn a blank window with:

```
cv.imshow(test)
cv.moveWindow(test, 1000,800)
cv.waitKey(1)
```

But when I try with haystack I get the error: `Failed capture: Can't convert object to 'str' for 'winname'`

```
cv.imshow("Ship Detection", haystack)
cv.moveWindow(haystack, 1000,800)
cv.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: debug your program. look at the value of `test`. why do you think imshow would return anything interesting? why are you trying to pass an image to `moveWindow`, or anything that isn't the string containing the window name?

Comment: Try cv2.moveWindow("Ship Detection",...

Comment: Replaced this cv.imshow(test) to haystack_img.show()

Comment: I didn't think it would spawn anything interesting, I was just checking that I could actually move a window. I can move a new window, I can't seem to move my existing window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cv.imshow("Ship Detection", haystack)
cv.moveWindow("Ship Detection", 1000,800)
cv.waitKey(1)
```

`moveWindow` wants the window name not the object.